# Visual Studio NET Core 3.1, can I develop on NET SDK 6.0.400 or only on SDK 3.1

Tags: .net, visual-studio, sdk

In Visual Studio 2019 I select .NET Core 3.1 (Long-term support) when I create my project, can I develop on .NET SDK 6.0.400,.NET Runtime 6.0.8, ASP.NET Core Runtime 6.0.8, and .NET Windows Desktop Runtime 6.0.8 or do I need to develop on .NET SDK 3.1?

Comment: .NET 5.0
.NET 5.0 merged the .NET 4.8 Framework and .NET Core 3.1 with additional functionality. To use .NET 5.0 with your projects, you will need to use the latest version Visual Studio 2019 which includes the .NET 5.0 Runtime.

.NET 6.0
.NET 6.0 is the latest version of the .NET Framework and was released on November 8, 2021. To use .NET 6.0 with your projects, you will need to use the current version of Visual Studio 2022 which includes the .NET 6.0 Runtime.

Answer (score 1):

You must use Visual Studio 2022 if you want to develop with .NET 6 SDK.
It it stated in the notes here: https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/6.0

Comment: .NET 5.0
.NET 5.0 merged the .NET 4.8 Framework and .NET Core 3.1 with additional functionality. To use .NET 5.0 with your projects, you will need to use the latest version Visual Studio 2019 which includes the .NET 5.0 Runtime.

.NET 6.0
.NET 6.0 is the latest version of the .NET Framework and was released on November 8, 2021. To use .NET 6.0 with your projects, you will need to use the current version of Visual Studio 2022 which includes the .NET 6.0 Runtime.

Answer (score 1):

From [Announcing .NET 6](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-net-6/#:%7E:text=.NET%206%20is%20supported%20with%20Visual%20Studio%202022,Visual%20Studio%202022%20%28which%20is%20also%20now%2064-bit%29..)

> .NET 6 is supported with Visual Studio 2022 and Visual Studio 2022 for
> Mac. It is not supported with Visual Studio 2019, Visual Studio for
> Mac 8, or MSBuild 16. If you want to use .NET 6, you will need to
> upgrade to Visual Studio 2022 (which is also now 64-bit). .NET 6 is
> supported with the Visual Studio Code C# extension.

Visual Studio 2019 for Mac (v8.10) supports it, though.

Comment: .NET 5.0
.NET 5.0 merged the .NET 4.8 Framework and .NET Core 3.1 with additional functionality. To use .NET 5.0 with your projects, you will need to use the latest version Visual Studio 2019 which includes the .NET 5.0 Runtime.

.NET 6.0
.NET 6.0 is the latest version of the .NET Framework and was released on November 8, 2021. To use .NET 6.0 with your projects, you will need to use the current version of Visual Studio 2022 which includes the .NET 6.0 Runtime.

Comment: True, but sadly NET 5.0 has reached the end of support date while 3.1 is still on the long term support line. See https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/dotnet-5-end-of-support-update/#:~:text=NET%205.0%20support%20will%20end%20on%20May%2010%2C,of.NET%2C%20which%20will%20be.NET%20Core%203.1%20and.NET%206.0. Still it is the last one available on VS2019, so, if you don't have any other reason to still use VS2019 you better to upgrade VS.

Answer (score 0):

.NET 5.0
.NET 5.0 merged the .NET 4.8 Framework and .NET Core 3.1 with additional functionality. To use .NET 5.0 with your projects, you will need to use the latest version Visual Studio 2019 which includes the .NET 5.0 Runtime.

.NET 6.0
.NET 6.0 is the latest version of the .NET Framework and was released on November 8, 2021. To use .NET 6.0 with your projects, you will need to use the current version of Visual Studio 2022 which includes the .NET 6.0 Runtime.